# HOW TO : A simple way to install Datatables (and Editor) with npm

Tags: npm, datatables

Installing Datatables, Editor and their options (`Select`, `RowGroup` etc.. ) can be quite tricky with the official [npm installation](https://datatables.net/download/npm). You have to install multiple dependencies, be cautious of the CSS versions you import and so on.

I had an hard time dealing with it so I share you a quite straightforward solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Datatables offers an excellent `download` option in the [download builder](https://datatables.net/download/), which allows you to the styling, packages and extensions you want and download them in a single folder.

So first of all:

- pick the configuration you want and then download the files (with concatenate option).

[image: Download builder]

Then :

- Copy the Datatable package into some local directory.
- Add a package.json file with the following

  ```
  { "name": "datatables-bundle",
    "version": "1.10.16",
    "description": "Datatables bundled",
    "main": "datatables.js",
    "author": {
    "name": "SpryMedia Ltd",
    "url": "http://datatables.net"
    }
  }
  ```
- go to your project directory
- Call `npm install ../datatables-local-package-path`.

Once this is done, I can require the bundled package with a single line:

```
window.dt = require('datatables-bundle');
```

for CSS :

```
//Datatables styles
@import "~datatables-bundle/datatables.min.css";
```

... and this works!

Editor and Tables are fully functional so are the options (`select`, `RowGroup`...).

It spares the difficulty of installing separately all the npm packages, the post install process (for Editor's licence) and so on.

Of course the package won't update by itself but this is a minor issue.